# Define a base route when using flask blueprints

Tags: python, flask, blueprint

I am currently using blueprints in my flask application. However, I would like to define a simple 'base' route ( '/' ) e.g. myapp.com/

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, this has nothing to do with Flask. To create route to home page, You would do something like this:

```
@app.route
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Visiting `/` on any site where this Flask app is deployed would lead to home page.

Now, in order to lead You to `myapp.com/`, You need to get `myapp.com` address, meaning You would need to buy that domain.